# How do you work with a GitHub repo inside Blender.app/.exe?

Tags: python, interface, add-on, development

What is a good method to update a GitHub repository without manually copy/pasting the entire repo into the Blender addons folder when developing Blender add-ons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a simple Python script that is callable from the terminal:
https://github.com/torrinworx/Blender_Dev_Tools

You can pull a repo into the Blender addons folder, or push the Blender folder to a GitHub repo. You can also delete the Blender repo. Instructions for operation are in the readme file at the above link.

I struggled developing Blender add-ons in the beginning, I hope this tool helps the community!

Answer (score 3):

I just symlink the addon file or folder into the `scripts/addons` directory so it updates automatically when you switch branches, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I use Visual Studio Code (VS-Code) with Blender. ([A tutorial for getting started](https://b3d.interplanety.org/en/using-microsoft-visual-studio-code-as-external-ide-for-writing-blender-scripts-add-ons/)).

VS-Code has excellent [github](https://github.com/) integration ([A tutorial for getting started](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/introduction-to-github-visual-studio-code/)).  It's also a reasonable code editor that is open source and portable to many operating systems, especially Linux and Windows.  I use it on the later.

My workflow is to maintain and edit the add-on's code using VS-Code; use VS-Code / github integration; and use the Blender integration tools to run the add-on in Blender from VS-Code.